# When I try to download flutterfire_cli, my cmd crashes

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to download the flutterfire_cli througth:
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

But when I even copy and paste this into command prompt, command prompt just crashes.

Comment: I got the same problem. You might not have git in your system.[for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75408553/cmd-close-itself-when-i-enter-dart-pub-global-activate-flutterfire-cli/75566499#75566499)

Answer (score -1):

please follow the next 3 single steps:

1.- Open a cmd window and try to install git using the next command: winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget

2.- After that install dart SDK with the command: choco install dart-sdk

3.- After install you should be running the command without trouble: dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli