# CMD close itself when i enter "dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, backend, firebase-cli

So i was trying to use firebase for my flutter backend. When i tried to enter the command "dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli" the cmd Suddenly close itself.

I tried to open the cmd as an administrator and run the command but it it still close itself.

Note: I already install the Firebase CLI via npm.

please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't heve install Git to your system. Try instal git.

Comment: Please edit your answer by correcting it in grammarly.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the git in your machine,
Install the [git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and then run

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

I hope this time you not get any error

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the next 3 single steps:

1.- Open a cmd window and try to install git using the next command:
winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget

2.- After that install dart SDK with the command:
choco install dart-sdk

3.- After install you should be running the command without trouble
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by `run cmd` from dart sdk file .

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reinstalling the dart SDK